# coffee script split function based on two conditions

Tags: javascript, regex, split, coffeescript

Trying to tweak a plugin written in coffee script. have a condition to split a string with delimiter pipe `'|'` if this pipe character is not escaped as `'\|'`.

```
"plus\+ | qual\= | pipe\| | minus\-".split'|'
```

i tried to achieve this with by adding a space `.split(' |')`, but sometimes it's not true.

Comment: what i am looking for is, able to provide the condition not \| at the same time, some thing like split(/<?!(\\)\|/)

Comment: Ok, but the string `plus\+ | qual\=` should be defined with `"plus\\+ | qual\\="` string literal.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/5xd1c0z1/, does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Using `.split` when the delimiter can be escaped is hard to get right, if you take escaped backslashes into account. Easier to match everything but the unescaped delimiters.

```
s = "plus\\+ | qual\\= | pipe\\| | minus\\-"
result = s.match(/(?:\\.|[^\\\|])+/g)

alert result
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try this